# how to write a proper selector for what is inside input box?

Tags: css, forms, css-selectors, inputbox

I have a form of inputbox and i need to write a good selector. I need to assign attributes only to what is inside inputbox. form looks like this:

```
<label></label>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="xxx" size="100" value="abcd" class="yyy" />
```

however, i have more elements of this class on my page.

what is the best way to go?

Comment: Where is your inputbox container? This is the most important part of writing a selector to catch all its descendants (knowing its ID/name). Also, what attribute of all the input elements will be shared in common?

Comment: <fieldset>
     <legend>thats my input box</legend>
                <p>
                    <label></label>
     <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="xxx" size="100"       value="abcd" class="yyy" />
            </fieldset>

Comment: If it's the class name your worried about, it's better if you name the class different as standard to something more appropriate, if you gave the source to someone else, would they understand what you was trying to achieve quickly? If not, look at naming things better, although pseudocode helps.

Comment: well im just writing css, so i cant edit html some else is responsible for it

Answer (score 0):

As you've added a class "yyy", you can just go ahead and do the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
.yyy {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #FF0000;
}
</style>
```

You can of course paste that HTML code above and plant it in your HTML document, but it's best practice to keep HTML and CSS away from each other.

So add this code in your head tag:

```
<link href="some/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And inside of style.css:

```
.yyy {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: Arial;
 color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: thx but the problem is i have more elements of class 'yyy' but i want to keep them look slightly different than what is going to be inside my input box

Comment: Okay, but if you don't want to rename the class, then stick another element around it: eg: <span class="demo"><input .... class="yyy"></span> then change the css opening line to: .demo .yyy { font-size: 14px;....

Comment: @mike Are you saying you have more non input elements using the class yyy? If so, why not target your input elements with the class yyy. 'input.yyy {}'

Comment: well no unfortunately i have couple more input boxes with the same class on the other pages which would be nice to look different

Comment: is there any way i can use the name from the form to write a selector for this certain inputbox?

Comment: You can use any name you wish, there are no restrictions, however, you can also make use of an id rather than a class. If you want them all to possibly look different, then you'd be best just doing yyy1, yyy2, yyy3 and so on, there is no harm having them all as classes or id's, however, you're only supposed to reference 1 id on a document at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either `input.yyy {}`, which will work on all browsers but if you have more than one input element on the page with a class of yyy, it will select all of them.

An alternative is input[name=xxx], using a new CSS3 selector, but this won't work in older browsers, so it depends how important it is that the style works everywhere.

Comment: great :) just be warned that it won't work in IE before v9, unless you use jQuery to assign the style instead.